# Eddystone, Is it possible to fetch the beacons location?

Tags: location, latitude-longitude, eddystone

I checked that the Beacon location information(latlong etc) can resister to the google restoration server. so now I want to make an Android application that displayed roughly current location to the user device. From Eddystone specification point of view, is it possible to get LatLong of nearest beacon from restoration server? if possible, could you let me know which API should i use?

thank you for your kindly support

Answer (score 0):

Most Eddystone beacons will be registered(I assume that will be the practical approach for most at least) on Google Cloud using [Proximity Beacon API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides?hl=en). See the [reference](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/) part for usage and your options.

I believe it's not possible to get "a nearest" beacon just by using lat-long unless that beacon belongs to you(registered by yourself), you will probably going to need some kind of observation data first, to obtain further information about the beacon.

Here is the [Github repo](https://github.com/google/beacon-platform) with iOS/Android sample applications to get you started.